# P adjusted values in Deseq2

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bioinformatics

I have a metabolic pathway dataset that I run through DESeq2 and my question is why some different p-values ended up having an equal p-adjusted?

```
baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE           stat            pvalue      padj
102.4139421 -2.779259157    0.879336287 -3.160632853    0.001574268 0.165229376
97.44804027 -2.295013504    0.735995467 -3.118244073    0.001819321 0.165229376
224.9746369 -1.223071776    0.400516301 -3.053737822    0.002260095 0.165229376
114.9366424 -1.813971541    0.621330508 -2.919495368    0.003505986 0.165229376
111.8579053 -1.748819203    0.620374587 -2.818972989    0.004817757 0.165229376
83.94472937 -2.147032598    0.771273039 -2.783751654    0.005373416 0.165229376
```

I do not think is related to the sample size (similar datasets give quite variable - significant results). I do not think there is anything particulary wrong with the results, I just would like to know a bit more about the reasons of the outcome. Also, some of the q values are NA.

Any answer, tip, or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: According to [*Love et al. 2014*](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-014-0550-8), DESeq2 uses the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure for multiple testing.